# If a token is returned to hand, is it considered dying?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

1. 1/1 Devil token (ala [Devils' Playground](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Devils%27%20Playground)) on board
2. [Just the Wind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Just%20the%20Wind) cast on the 1/1 Devil
3. Token gets removed from board
4. ?? Devil does 1 damage to target creature or player ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, it doesn't die. "Dies" has a specific meaning:

> 700.4. The term dies means “is put into a graveyard from the battlefield.”

The token does cease to exist once in the player's hand, but that's due to other rules, and that's not considered dying either:

> 110.5f A token that’s phased out, or that’s in a zone other than the battlefield, ceases to exist. This is a state-based action; see rule 704. (Note that if a token changes zones, applicable triggered abilities will trigger before the token ceases to exist.)

But, this has an interesting implication that a token can die and is temporarily in the graveyard, thus satisfying death triggers.

Comment: For added effect:
Tokens still "die", but then they are removed from the graveyard immediately as a state-based action.

Comment: This could use a mention of the rule that *does* cause the token to stop existing when bounced. That would give the opportunity to show that it stops existing without rule 700.4 applying.

Comment: If it doesn't die, then the added ability doesn't trigger.